# Splitting dataframe into different columns using Python

Tags: python, pandas, split

My dataframe has 251 lines and only one column. But I want to split this data into separated columns using pandas, specifically.
The text file that I am using to acquire data looks like this,
[image: Text File Data]

But using the following code, it results in:

```
import pandas as pd

directory = 'A://'

spGlass = 'Glass.txt'

fileAir = os.path.join(directory,spGlass)

dataAir = pd.read_csv(fileAir,skiprows=2)
```

[image]

**Question**: Is there a way to split these data into different columns as it is presented on text file using Pandas??

Comment: You maybe better off reading `dataAir = pd.read_csv(fileAir, sep='\s\s+', header=3)`

Comment: To help we need more information about your dataset. can you upload it somewhere? and to what are expected columns and what are the separation criteria

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang it worked pretty well. I knew I was not so far. Thanks again!